# Eclipse PHP Zend: running old script even though it has been modified and saved?

Tags: php, eclipse, zend-debugger, zend-server

i am running eclipse php with zendserver and debugging with zend debugger. that all worked. however, i just reinstalled windows 7 due to a computer crash and dragged over my eclipse folder from my old windows to my new (current) installation of windows.

when i edited my old file, index.php, i saved it then ran in debug mode, but it looks exactly the same no matter how much i edit it. what could be the cause of this?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Garrett, I ran into this exact issue when I first installed Zend Server. I'm not 100% sure your issue is the same as mine, but it might be worth checking the following. It has to do with Zend Studio not having write permissions to Zend Server's htdocs, due to it being installed with Admin rights.

If you find your files in: C:\Users\YOUR USERNAME\appdata\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files\Zend then you're having the same issue. Changing the directory permissions on your htdocs directory should resolve it.

Then again, it might be something completely different.

Comment: it was set to read-only, so i've unchecked that and restarted my apache but it still cant find the server. this is so weird :S

Comment: i had to move it to C:\ to give it the right permissions. you had the right idea tho =)

Answer (score 0):

Is there a way to clear the cache perhaps? Sometimes when you view stuff through some kind of development framework it can use the system's own browser as a base, maybe try clearing the cache of all the browsers on your machine

Comment: Thats really strange! Perhaps you could try recreating index.php from scratch and try copy and pasting every into it?

Comment: i just deleted it and remade it and now it says it can't find the file when i try debugging it =S